# CONVERT a dynamic table data of date columns to HTML for sending email in SQL

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, email, smtp

I have a dynamic table data as below

| territory | 01-May-2021 | 02-May-2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| INDIA | 10 | 30 |
| UAE | 20 | 80 |
| USA | 300 | 10 |

Every day when we run the script a new column gets inserted with the current day.

I need this table data to be converted to HTML and send in EMAIL body to the respective recipients each day.

As this table is having dynamic data as date column each day kindly help.

I am using the `sendmail -t`  function for triggering the mail from database.

Comment: Adding new data as columns - that's probably the biggest sin you can make in an RDBMS and will make querying harder not easier. Suggest you reconsider your data model, those columns should be `rows`

Comment: Normalise your design. The date should be a single column, with a separate row for each date (and territory). Then all you need to is `INSERT` the data, not fiddle with the table's definition every time. What happens after around 2 years and 10 months, when you reach the maximum 1,024 columns?

Comment: Also in addition to your table design issues, sending pretty html emails from the database, while you can techinically do it, should really be formatted and sent by a separate application; there's no magic 'format as html' option, you'd need to build your css and html layout manually and repeatedly test it by previewing in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

> Every day when we run the script a new column gets inserted with the current day.

This is broken.  Are you aware that SQL Server has a limit on the number of columns?  Are you aware that adding a new column requires rewriting all the existing data?  Are you aware the by adding a new column, you cannot write queries?

What you should be doing is adding new *rows*.  Each row should have (at least) three columns:

- `region`
- `date`
- `amount`

Then adding new data is just adding rows to the table.

If you need data in the above format, you can use a view to structure the table you need.  You can recreate the view every day -- when you are adding the new rows.